# handle ajax request and send response java servlet

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, response

I have an ajax request function (written in JavaScript) and Java Servlet that handles this request. I need to get all request parameters and if it succeeded then send back a confirmation that it has succeeded. How I can send a confirmation message? As an attribute, like `{isSuccess: true}`. My code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
    IOException {
    Enumeration<?> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
    while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String paramName = (String) paramNames.nextElement();
        // storing data fn
    }
    // how to send back a message here?
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax/4113258#4113258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `PrintWriter` object by calling `HttpServletResponse#getWriter` and write your `String`.

```
response.getWriter().write("{isSuccess: true}");
```

Comment: welcome, if you deem my answer correct, you should mark it "Accepted".